# Sort collection in alphabetic order

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to print my collection sorted alphabeticall. Here's what I've tried inside my controller:

```
public function listForCategories(Category $category)
    {
        return $category->subcategories->sortBy('title');
    }
```

But It's not sorting my output :/ Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$category->subcategories->sortBy('title')->values()->all();

I don't know exact hierarchy but you can use the solution as per your needs:

The sortBy method sorts the collection by the given key. The sorted collection keeps the original array keys,

so in this example, we'll use the values method to reset the keys to consecutively numbered indexes:

Here is an example :

$category = collect([
   ['title' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],

['title' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],

['title' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],

]);

$sorted = $category->sortBy('title')->values()->all();

Result-:
[
['title' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],

['title' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],

['title' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
]

Answer (score 2):

try  `return $category->subcategories->orderBy('title');`

Comment: `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.` :/

Comment: https://admin.test/categories/subcategories/3/list
When You go to this URL you receive all subcategories for category which has id '3' and output should be sorted alphabetically. I'm using relations so I can get all subcategories for category like $category->subcategories

Comment: title field is in Category table?

Comment: Yes and also in subcategories, and i want all subcategories for category.

Answer (score 1):

The `sortBy` method sorts the internal fields, however, it preserves the original keys, therefore, if you want to have the sorted values, you should call the `values()` method after you've sorted the collection. That way you get the sorted collection back.

`return $category->subcategories->sortBy('title')->values()->all();`

Comment: Thank you it's working! I thought it'd display all values but it "saves" and uses the relation :)

Comment: You're welcome, the Collection class doesn't always behave exactly the way you'd expect :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using orderBy when you retrieve them from the database (I'm assuming you do)

```
public function listForCategories(Category $category)
{
    return $category->subcategories()->orderBy('title')->get();
}
```